# AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot not calling the callback function

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot to call a function by following [Flutter Documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager).

My code is as follows

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 static Future<void> printHello() {
    print("Called");
    final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    final int isolateId = Isolate.current.hashCode;
    print("[$now] Hello, world! isolate=${isolateId} function='$printHello'");
  }
 
  Widget build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Click Me"),
            onPressed: () async {
              print("Button pressed");
              await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(const Duration(seconds: 5),
                      helloAlarmID, printHello)
                  .then((value) => print("Res: $value"));
              print("Done");
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting the output as
[image]

after waiting more than 5 seconds
The callback function is not getting called.
Any help will be appreciated.

App UI is as follows
[image]

Edit: After like 2-3 minutes got this output

```
I/akhar.alarm_ap(15894): Thread[7,tid=15938,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xd72b3000,peer=0x153c2a28,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/akhar.alarm_ap(15894): 
I/akhar.alarm_ap(15894): Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
I/akhar.alarm_ap(15894): Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 3079(323KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 56% free, 1187KB/2723KB, paused 334us total 20.864ms
I/akhar.alarm_ap(15894): Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 6876(270KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(80KB) LOS objects, 56% free, 1189KB/2725KB, paused 202us total 5.984ms
```

Edit 2: The main function is as follows

```
final int helloAlarmID = 0;
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: What is the `helloAlarmID`?

Comment: @PreetShah I declared it as a constant
`final int helloAlarmID = 0;`

Comment: @PrakharGupta I'm facing the same issue , did you get to trigger your function ?